# AlarmManager intent=null

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Here's the code I'm using to try and set up an AlarmManager:

```
feedingIntent = new Intent(this, FeedingAlarmReceiver.class);
    feedingPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, feedingIntent, 0);
    feedingAM = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    feedingAM.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60000, feedingPI);
```

I basically want the feedingIntent to trigger after a minute after a button press. When I check logcat after I press the button it says my intent is null:

```
V/AlarmManager﹕ sending alarm PendingIntent{435f7ac8: PendingIntentRecord{435b8ed0 com.example.parentingreminders broadcastIntent}}, intent=null, type=ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, count=1, when=959128249, repeateInterval=0
```

This is my first time using AlarmManager and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the corresponding action in feedingIntent to trigger the receiver

```
feedingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_XXXX);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! How would that plug into my code above? Like this?


    `feedingIntent = new Intent(this, FeedingAlarmReceiver.class);
        feedingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        feedingPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, feedingIntent, 0);
        feedingAM = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);`

Comment: Your receiver should have have action in the intent-filter in androidmanifest.xml. Using feedingIntent.setAction(xxxx); to set it.